# How can I have access to Org.Apache.Http.Impl.client.DefaultHttpclient in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, https, xamarin

I'm trying to deal with a long time HTTPS request. My original code, which uses the ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback, adds at least a 5 seconds delay to the server response, I have a class coded in java which is really really faster, and I'm trying to translate it to C#.

Here is my translation, the two last lines don't compile and are driving me crazy, how can I instantiate a ThreadSafeClientConnManager and a DefaultHttpClient ?

```
    using Org.Apache.Http.Conn.Schemes;
    using Org.Apache.Http.Conn;
    using Org.Apache.Http.Conn.Ssl;
    using Org.Apache.Http.Params;



    IHttpParams httpParams;
    IClientConnectionManager ccm;

    KeyStore store = KeyStore.GetInstance (KeyStore.DefaultType);
    store.Load (null, null);
    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFact = new SSLSocketFactory (store);
    sslSocketFact.HostnameVerifier = SSLSocketFactory.AllowAllHostnameVerifier;

    httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpProtocolParams.SetVersion(httpParams, Org.Apache.Http.HttpVersion.Http11);
    HttpProtocolParams.SetContentCharset(httpParams, "UTF-8");

    SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
    schemeRegistry.Register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.SocketFactory, 80));
    schemeRegistry.Register(new Scheme("https", sslSocketFact, 443));

    new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(httpParams, schemeRegistry);
    HttpClient client =  new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, httpParams);
```